# When click edittext layout go up

Tags: android, xml

I tried  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"  but its not working. After the enter password user must click end but I need to be able to see my login button - but how ? :)

My problem is this : 
[image]

I added to manifest  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" but nothing changes.

My xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="56dp"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:paddingRight="24dp"
        android:id="@+id/touchInterceptor">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="133dp"
            android:layout_height="137dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/elma_logo4"
            android:layout_weight="2.00" />
        <!--  Email Label -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
            <EditText android:id="@+id/input_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:hint="Email"
                      android:focusable="false"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <!--  Password Label -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
            <EditText android:id="@+id/input_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:hint="@string/ifre"
                      android:focusable="false"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Şifremi Hatırla"
            android:id="@+id/cb_Hatirla"
            android:layout_weight="2.00"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_login"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:text="Giriş"/>

        <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />


        <TextView android:id="@+id/link_forgotpass"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                  android:text="Şifremi Unuttum?"
                  android:gravity="center"
                  android:textSize="16dip"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/link_signup"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:text="Hesabınız yok mu ? Hemen Oluşturun!"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="16dip"/>



    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: your question is totally not understandable..

Comment: I mean when i click password edittext i want to see my login button

Comment: I think you need to manage `actionDone` after user done typing with password. which automatically hide keyboard and you can able to see your login button.

Comment: When you done typing password already hide keyboard but its a bit boring for user waiting close the keyboard and go click login ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `android:imeOptions="actionNext"` to `input_email` EditText. Which helps you to show `next` button on keyboard to navigate `input_password`.

And put `android:imeOptions="actionDone"` to `input_password` EditText, which helps you to show `Done` button on keyboard. 
When click on `Done` button you can able to see you `btn_login`.

It is proper way to navigate user in EditText.

See [Specifying the Input Method Type](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html) for EditText.

I hope its helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Use it on your manifies file
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden"
            >